# Multiprocessing a loop in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following code that I want to speed up (using multiprocessing).

```
def main(arg1):
    data=[]
    #Calculate new argument arg2
    for i in range(n):
       data.append(function(z,i,arg2))
```

Where `z` in a 2D array.
My idea was to do it the following way, but I am not sure this will speed up the process.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import itertools

def function_star(a_b_c):
   return function(*a_b_c)

def main(arg1):
   #Calculate new argument arg2
   pool=Pool()
   i=range(n)
   out=pool.map(function_star, i, itertools.repeat(z),itertools.repeat(arg2) )
   pool.close() 

if __name__=="__main__":
  main(arg1)
```

Is this indeed the most efficient way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your code block correctly you want to have `function` called with always the same `z`, and `arg1` but with `i` being a range (I am a bit unsure because the code you pasted will not work, as `map` only takes one iterable and you're giving 3)

If this is the case, then `partial` solves your issue:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def function(i, z, arg2):
    print(z, i, arg2)

def main(arg1):
   #Calculate new argument arg2
   pool=Pool()
   i=range(n)

   out=pool.map(partial(function, z=5, arg2=3), i)
   pool.close() 

if __name__=="__main__":
  main(arg1)
```

note that you need to change the order of arguments in your function so that the changing `i` parameter is at first position.

If you care about speed, you should add a third argument to `map` with the chunksize. This makes that a process asks for a `chunksize` packet from the main process so you have a smaller numer of communications between the main process and the child processes.